# Show iframe with swf file in fancybox

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, flash

I'm trying to get my head around an IE8 issue with the jQuery fancybox plugin (version 2)

I need to show a div with some text and an iframe in it, in a fancybox. The page that gets loaded in the iframe contains a flash application. My code is as follows:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#myDiv">

<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">
    <iframe width="580" height="420" style="overflow-y: hidden;" scrolling="no" src="http://urlwithflashapp/"></iframe>     
    <div style="width:550px">
        Some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();  
});
```

This works in every other browser than IE8. In IE8, the flash application never shows up. It just displays an empty, white box with a border in it.

Does anyone know of a workaround on this? :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your IE has flash add-on/plugin installed? ... does the iframe display outside fancybox (remove `style="display:none;"` to test) ?

Comment: Hi JFK, thanks for your input :) Greatly appreciated! Yes, I can see any other SWF in IE8+, so I guess it is installed ;) I tried removing the display:none; from the div and then it displays just fine on the page.. Did I miss something in regards of fancybox options maybe?

Comment: Does this work for you [http://jsfiddle.net/tcymh/](http://jsfiddle.net/tcymh/) ? at least if works fine in IE7

Comment: Hi JFK, thanks a lot :) Nope, unfortunately not. The problem is the exact same: the position where the SWF should be is just plain white..

Comment: Should mention that I'm testing this in IE10, but set the browser to IE8 standards mode :)

Comment: that explain everything, I bet it works with a native IE8 ... BTW, I don't think is a good idea to have hidden inline iframes; you may have your own reasons though.

Comment: JFK, thanks a lot! :) Will test it on a native IE8 then.